# Semantics based code search

Tags: search, semantics, code-search-engine, code-search

We have a large number of repositories. We want to implement a semantics(functionality) based code search on those repositories. Right now, we already have implemented keyword based code search in which we crawled through all the repository files and indexed them using elasticsearch. But that doesn't solve our problem as some of the repositories are poorly commented and documented, thus searching for specific codes/libraries become difficult.

**So my question is:** Is there any opensource libraries or any previous work done in this field which could help us index the semantics of the repository files, so that searching the code becomes easy and this would also help us in re-usability of the codes. I have found some research papers like [Semantic code browsing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02565), [Semantics-based code search](http://cs.brown.edu/~spr/research/s6.html) etc. but were of no use as there was no actual implementation given. So can you please suggest some good libraries or projects which could help me in achieving the same.

P.S:-Moreover, companies like Koders, Google, cocycles.com etc. started their code search based on functionality. But most of them have shut down their operations without giving any proper feedback, can anyone please tell me what kind of difficulties they are facing.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I wrote  https://github.com/google/zoekt , which uses ctags-based understanding of code to improve ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [insight.io](http://www.insight.io)

It provides semantic search and browsing 
[image]

[image]